# Android application for 'mobile' not for watch shows missing feature : watch

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-wear-2.0

LOG

> Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
> Retry
>
> AVD shows error: missing feature: WATCH

I was working on a project for some time and it was working properly. I recently tried making a few changes and it started showing this error. The app is a normal mobile application

Answer (score 0):

hi this error comes when you try to run your 'wearable' app(=module) on 'mobile' simulator.

**if you don't have wearable module in your project,**

1. check if your manifest has something related to the "wearable". if you have, please remove the line

```py
    <uses-library
                android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
                android:required="true" />
```

2. check if you have any wearable device on your simulator. if have,
   delete

**if you have wearable and mobile modules, Understand that**

- your project has 2 modules. (1. mobile 2.wearble)
- run your module on right device ( mobile app on mobile simulator,
  wearable app on wearable simulator.)

**Trouble Shooting**

- please check on left side of your device option. you probably
  selected wearing app.
- make sure that your module (Red Box) is matched with your
  simulator(Yellow Box)

[image]